# Unable to reference highlight id of listview qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml, highlight, referenceerror

I have a listview highlight component whose id I need to use outside of this component(both inside and outside listview) but whatever I try I get a `reference error: Id is not defined.` Unable to find a workaround for this. I read somewhere that since type of highlight is component, it can't be used outside of it. But I really need to use this id outside. Could anyone help pls
A small outline of the code I have at the moment is

```
ListView {
    id: listId
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            boxId.visible = false
        } //unable to use 'boxId' like this. Getting reference error
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {}

    highlight: Rectangle {
        id: boxId
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access `Listview.highlight` component due to the scope limitation. It can simply not be exist at the accessing time. And you shouldn't do that, just think [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). If you still want to follow an imperative style, use [Listview.highlightItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightItem-prop) to refer the highlighted item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the item in highlight does not always exist when you try to access it in in `MouseArea`. For that reason it cannot be referenced directly from this scope.

You could try something like this to only access it when it exists:

```
ListView {
    id: listId
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var item = ListView.highlightItem

            if (item) {
                item.visible = false
            }
        }
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {}

    highlight: Rectangle {
        id: boxId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandro4912 for copying my comment :-)

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea to give a proper code example to the things mentioned in your comment.